# Python - defining global name datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to create a function where I use various functions from the datetime module, such as strftime, strptime and timedelta.

I feel like I've tried everything, but every time I am told this:

```
      4 date = '2012.09.07'
      5 
----> 6 q = net(date)
      7 print q

/Users/fb/Documents/Python_files/test_function.pyc in net(date)
      1 def net(date):
----> 2     b = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y.%m.%d')
      3     c = b.strftime('%d:%m:%y')
      4     return c

NameError: global name 'datetime' is not defined
```

I've read that others probably experience the same problem as I, namely ' It works in the python interpreter but not in the script'. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: what is variable `a` here `b = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y.%m.%d')` ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to import the `datetime` object *in your module*:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

at the top of `test_function.py`.

In your interpreter session you probably already imported the object.

Your whole module will then look like:

```
from datetime import datetime

def net(date):
    b = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y.%m.%d')
    c = b.strftime('%d:%m:%y')
    return c
```

where I replaced `a` with `date`, since that is the name of the actual argument to the function.

Note that the `datetime` *module* contains a `datetime` *class*, which is the only thing imported here. If you need access to the `date` and `timedelta` classes as well, import these explicitly (`from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta`) or import *just* the module and refer to the contents as attributes (`import datetime`, then `datetime.datetime.strptime()` and `datetime.date.today()`, etc.).

Comment: Great answer, but perhaps include a warning that `from datetime import datetime` masks the module name and makes it impossible to access other classes such as Date and TimeDelta later. That is a common issue here on SO.